# are there any cross platform tools that will turn a responsive website into a native mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, titanium, appcelerator

We are trying to pass off the mobile version of our responsive site as an app, making it look and feel as much like a native app as possible. We are familiar with platforms like phonegap/cordova/appcellerator, but it doesn't seem like those are exactly what we need in this case.

We have a responsive website. We're looking for a cross platform mobile app that will allow us to:

- install like a native app via app store/play store
- have a configurable / brandable icon
- the only functionality is that it
  displays the responsive (mobile) version of our website, with no
  borders or navigation, just like in a browser. No additional in-app
  funtionality.

We are thinking about writing something like this (basically a borderless browser with our icon) but it seems like someone would have done this by now. Any ideas?

Thanks everyone.

re: phonegap/cordova etc.  We are under the (perhaps mistaken) impression that they require an HTML5 version of your app be re-written (at least tweaked) and then then put inside the phonegap/cordova wrapper for deployment. We have two issues with that:

- We don't want this app to reference an internal "wrapped" version of
  our website, we want it to reference our live site so when we update
  the live site, we don't have to update the app.
- we don't want to have to rewrite any of our existing code to work in
  the wrapper. It's an older asp.net site, but the responsive version
  works perfectly in a mobile browser.

Comment: "the only functionality is that it displays the responsive (mobile) version of our website, with no borders or navigation, just like in a browser. No additional in-app funtionality." Pretty sure that requirement will be an issue if you plan to use "stores". IIRC, both Apple and Google decline apps that do nothing else other than invoke a webview and navigate to a page. They have to provide some functionality of their own.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils thanks.  We can add some token functionality (push notifications, etc) if need be.  Are you familiar with any tools that do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appcelerator is the best approach for this.  It would take just a few lines of code in the app.js file that Appcelerator uses:

```
    var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
    var webview = Ti.UI.createWebView({
        url: 'http://yourwebsite.com'
    });

    win.add(webview);
    win.open();
```

Now, there are a few other options you would need to specify (i.e. if you want fullscreen, etc.), but for the most part, that would be your code. All your icons are in the /resources/iphone directory for iOS, and /resources/android for Android.

All the API information for the UI in the Titanium SDK is at http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI

Comment: thanks....two questions about this:  1) can you customize the app icon? and 2) do the app stores (apple/google) typically push through appcelerator apps or are we going to run into the issue that @ChiefTwoPencils mentions?  We can add some token functionality if needed.

Comment: @3z33etm Sorry, many months late in this reply. Sure, you can make the app icon whatever you want.  They are just .png files, and different sizes for different platforms (retina, iphone, ipad, etc).  As far as getting approved, it's possible you may need more than just a webview.  Even if you added just a simple native menu that would navigate to different parts of your website in the webview, that would take care of any approval issues.  But, you can always try and see if they let it through.

Comment: @SethDavis That documentation link is 404'ed.